# Unity fresh project: Found conflicts between different versions of "System" that could not be resolved

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am using Visual Studio and Unity 2017 on a Mac.
When I open any project, or even create a new one, when I try to debug in Visual Studio I always get warning messages:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.8.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. (MSB3277) (TestProject)

For a fresh project I get errors regarding System, System.Xml and mscorlib. If I open older projects (that worked on Windows) I may get even more.

This warning message completely breaks my breakpoints, making them appear allow and renders debugging impossible.

Not sure if this relates, but prior to this I have installed a few instances of Unity that now coexist on the Mac (Unity 2017, Unity 5.4 and 5.5).

Please help, I have never experienced something like this on Windows, so my guess is that it's Mac related. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like a question for the Unity support forum, nevertheless, I would try to uninstall and reinstall everything.

Comment: Getting the same warning.  Any luck?

Comment: I cleanly reinstalled unity and visual studio multiple times, but the issue persists. Sadly, for now I switched to monodevelop.